# Как спрарсить текс с книги форматов FB2 EPUB MOBI PDF PYTHON

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Я делаю бота для телеги и я сделал так чтоб текст или файл txt читался и озвучивался(отправлялся как голосовое сообщение), теперь хочу также сделать и с книгами. Сейчас надумал что можно как то спарсить но увы голова не варит как спарсить книгу статей не нашел. ПОМОГИТЕ!

```
# Получаем данные о файле
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
 def handle_docs(message):  
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.document.file_id)
    document = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    # Сохраняем файл в папке
    with open('audio/voice.txt', 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(document)
    # чтение слов из файла 
    with open('audio/voice.txt', 'rb') as f:
        tts = gtts.gTTS(f.read().decode('utf-8'), lang='ru')
        tts.save('audio/voice.mp3')
        bot.send_voice(message.chat.id, open('audio/voice.mp3', 'rb'))
        
@bot.message_handler() 
def send_text(message):
    tts = gtts.gTTS(message.text, lang='ru')
    tts.save('audio/voice.mp3')
    bot.send_voice(message.chat.id, open('audio/voice.mp3', 'rb'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ваше сообщение отправлено!')
```

Comment: код каряво скопировался сории

Comment: Каждый формат кардинально отличается от другого формата, каждый формат парсится по-разному. PDF может вообще в принципе не содержать текста, а быть просто набором сканов - такое парсить только через распознавание текста, это вообще отдельная задача.

Comment: @insolor
 а если взять самую популярную FB2 то как мне текст распарсить?

Comment: fb2 - это xml файл. В принципе можно взять любую библиотеку для парсинга xml.